# "Look at there!" or "Look there!"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which of the orders is more idiomatic

> "Look **at** there!" (see this thing there)

or

> "Look there!" (see this thing there)

?

Answer (score 3):

"Look at there" is ungrammatical. "To look **at**" expects an object, but "there" is a preposition and cannot serve as an object. You can say "look (over) there" or "look at that."

Comment: _There_ is not a preposition, but otherwise I agree.

Comment: @ColinFine [Are you sure?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/184342/108753)

Comment: @TypeIA: As commented in that link: [*It should be clear that the term 'preposition' is by no means ideal for our purposes.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3036/cerberus-reinstate-monica) And I *still* don't see how knowing such terminology would help people actually learn how to understand and use English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree on the last point. I'm not doing the nitpicking here.

Answer (score 2):

"At" will never be correct.  Also this phrase will not be said.  Instead you can say "Look over there" or "Look at that".